# Can some one notice what is wrong with this view. i'm getting ParseError: "Invalid view definition"?

Tags: python, odoo-13

raise ValidationError(_('Invalid view %s definition in %s') % (view_name, view.arch_fs))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Invalid view david.form.view definition in davids_module/views/form_views.xml
None" while parsing /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/davids_module/views/form_views.xml:2, near

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record id="davids_module_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">david.list.view</field>
        <field name="model">david</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree>
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="surname" />
                <field email="email" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="action_davids_module_profile" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Form Views</field>
        <field name="rec_model">forms.view</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree, form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="davids_module_root_menu" name="David" />
    <menuitem id="davids_module_sub_menu" parent="davids_module_root_menu" />
    <menuitem id="davids_module_menu" action="action_davids_module_profile" parent="davids_module_sub_menu"/>
</odoo>
```

MODEL:

```
from odoo import models, fields


class FormsViews(models.Model):

    _name = "david"

    name = fields.Char(string="Form name")
    surname = fields.Char(string="Username")
    email = fields.Char(string="Email")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your **`xml`** file

```
<record id="action_davids_module_profile" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Form Views</field>
    <field name="res_model">david</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree, form</field>
</record>
```